# Not able to retrieve Build info using spring-boot-actuators through /info endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

we are trying to take advantage of spring-boot-actuator to retrieve build info through /info endpoint i'm getting empty "{}" object as response these are my pom configurations

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

i made sure build-info. properties is created in my target/META-INF/classes folder through build-info goal

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

please let me know if i'm missing anything. The end point itself seem's to be accessible  not sure if i have to do anything else as the documentation say's http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html if build-info properties file is present that build-info properties by default are exposed via /info end point

Note : we are not using application.yml in the project, also we will not be able to upgrage the starter-parent to 1.4.Release at this time

Comment: Mixing versions of Spring Boot isn't a good idea as it's completely untested and will also give you a mixture of incompatible versions. For example 1.4 requires Spring Framework 4.3, but your parent configuration means that you'll be using 4.2. If you can't upgrade the parent at this time then I wouldn't try to use any of 1.4 at this time either

Comment: Yep agree with you Andy

Comment: I just verified it with Spring Boot 2.1.7 and it is exactly working with the plugin configuration described in the question.
Furthermore, in addition to spring-boot-starter-actuator I am configuring spring-boot-starter-web in dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You are only pretending you're using Spring Boot 1.4. Overriding individual versions like you are doing is really an awful idea. Since you haven't changed the parent, you indeed get the starter for 1.4 but the actual actuator module is still `1.3.1`. It does not work because the code that detects the build info simply isn't there.

Please perform a proper upgrade to 1.4

Comment: i never pretended i'm using 1.4  clearly mentioned the parent is 1.3.1 ..not sure how u draw that conclusion.. i already identified that upgrading to 1.4 release would solve my issue which i mentioned in the note  ...but like i mentioned it is not option at this time

Comment: Also spring-boot-starter-actuator is separate dependency from parent ..so not sure why the actual actuator module will be 1.3.1

Comment: I can answer that question but it will not help. You just can't use Spring Boot 1.3.1 and then swap ONE dependency to another version. Just don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can only rely on [Spring Boot 1.3.1](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-application-info-automatic-expansion) then you need to follow the documentation for that version. You can see that documentation differs from the [Spring Boot 1.4](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-application-info-autoconfigure) documentation and as such a different method was made available in Spring Boot 1.4 to expose the build information.